# C# ~ A Few questions about List<>

Tags: c#, list

I don't usually develop on Windows but recently I have had to do a bit of work with C# and I'm trying to get my head around a few things. I've been looking through the MSDN but cant quite find what I'm looking for.

Anyway as I understand it a List is indexed, much like an array. However if I deleted an item at position X using RemoveAt() would it then shift all the items so that a new item now filled position X? Or would position X just be empty?

Also using Remove() seems fairly straight forward if you have a List of strings or integers, but if you have a list of objects is it possible to use Remove() to delete an item where an object field has a specific value?

For example

Say i have List where each car object has a make, model & color.

Could i do something along the lines of

```
 cars.Remove(cars.color="red");
```

I'm sure that is horribly wrong but I am coming from a PHP background so im pretty confused about alot of the syntax at the moment.

Thanks

Comment: Thanks, exactly the sort of answer i was looking for.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

`List<T>` will not get holes.
Removing an item will shift all subsequent items up by one.

You can remove all items that match a condition by calling `RemoveAll()` with a lambda expression:

```
list.RemoveAll(o => o.Color == "Red");
```

Answer (score 3):

> if I deleted an item at position X using RemoveAt() would it then
>   shift all the items so that a new item now filled position X?

Yes.

> if you have a list of objects is it possible to use Remove() to delete
>   an item where an object field has a specific value?

Yes, use the `RemoveAll` method:

```
cars.RemoveAll(c => c.color == "red");
```

Answer (score 0):

When items are removed the spot is taken up by the next one. As lists are collections you can use lambda with remove all

```
Cars.RemoveAll( x=> x.colour == "red");
```

Will remove all re cars.